# jq get first value by priority and condition

Tags: json, conditional-statements, jq

I have following json:

```
{
  "Detail": {
    "Response": [
      {
        "ID": "8000000D-1483989576",
        "Name": "",
        "FullName": "FullName 1"
      },
      {
        "ID": "8000000C-1483985849",
        "Name": "Name 1"
      },
      {
        "ID": "80000006-1481277410",
        "Name": "Name 2",
        "FullName": "FullName 2"
      },
      {
        "ID": "8000000B-1481537384",
        "Name": "Name 3"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create another json that will consider the non-empty/not null `.Name` as priority otherwise get `.FullName` regardless if it's empty or null, the final json would look like following:

```
[
  {
    "id": "8000000D-1483989576",
    "name": "FullName 1"
  },
  {
    "id": "8000000C-1483985849",
    "name": "Name 1"
  },
  {
    "id": "80000006-1481277410",
    "name": "FullName 2"
  },
  {
    "id": "8000000B-1481537384",
    "name": "Name 3"
  }
]
```

The temporary solution I got is to use `join`

```
jq '[.Detail.Response[] | {id: .ID, name: [.Name, .FullName] | join("") }]'
```

But of course, it'll only work if `.FullName` is empty or null.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you on your way:

```
.Detail.Response[]
| { id: .ID, Name: (if .Name != "" then .Name else .FullName end) }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figure out a way to do it using `map` and `select`.

```
jq '[.Detail.Response[] | {id: .ID, name: [.Name, .FullName] | map(select(length > 0)) | first }]'
```